# get access_token from code

Tags: android, instagram-api

I have the `code` and now I want to get `access_token` from the `code` I have received.
I tried to get `code` in this way but I didn't get any result in `username` or other variables!

```
try {
    String client_secret = "aeddb1f83bd44eb08ebc3cfc357cb462";
    String tokenURLString = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token" + "?client_id=" + client_id + "&client_secret=" + client_secret + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri + "&grant_type=authorization_code";
    URL url = new URL(tokenURLString);
    HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpsURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
    httpsURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream());
    outputStreamWriter.write("client_id=" + client_id +
            "&client_secret=" + client_secret +
            "&grant_type=authorization_code" +
            "&redirect_uri=" + "http://www.mycodingexperience.blog.ir/" +
            "&code=" + code);

    outputStreamWriter.flush();
    String response = streamToString(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream());
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
    String accessTokenString = jsonObject.getString("access_token"); //Here is your ACCESS TOKEN
    String id = jsonObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("id");
    String username = jsonObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("username");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

how can I get the `access_token` in Explicit?

Comment: what `response` are u getting, print it

Comment: @krisrak I get nothing from `response`! actually the whole not working but I get that code from this [link](http://www.b2cloud.com.au/uncategorized/instagram-integration-in-an-android-app/)